# Bootstrap datepicker change minDate/startDate from another datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

There are two datepickers in my page and both are of bootstrap. The condition is only that Start date never High with respect to End Date. Means End date Attribute (minDate) must be changed when Start Date changed by datepicker and same when End Date Changed, the minrange of calendar of Start Date datepicker should be according to End Date Value.

I hope you understand my problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
      $("#startdate").datepicker({
       
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: true,
       
       
      }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#enddate').datetimepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });
    
        $("#enddate").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<input type="text" placehoder="Start Date" id="startdate"/>
<input type="text" placehoder="End Date" id="enddate"/>
```

Comment: please consider re-phrasing your question / putting examples, you'll get more answers :)

Comment: You call a wrong method `datetimepicker` in line `$('#enddate').datetimepicker('setStartDate', minDate);`

Comment: OK, then what is correct method ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsodjsyv/) doing what you want. As pqdong commented you were calling datetimepicker instead of datepicker when setting end date.

Here is the working javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#startdate").datepicker({
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#enddate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });

    $("#enddate").datepicker()
        .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#startdate').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
        });

});
```

Comment: Nice solution! What if I want to setStartDate to selected.date value plus 5 days? Thanks,

Comment: @sidpat You can add 5 days to the value a few ways. The following is probably easiest: `var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 5));`

Comment: You saved me ... Thank you so much

Comment: @Razzildinho how to set minDate in bootstrap datepicker??

Comment: @Gulshan Does the code above not work for you? `$('#enddate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);` This line should set the minimum date for your datepicker.

Comment: @Razzildinho i got my solution..i want to set today's date as a startdate :)

Comment: I just use `var minDate = new Date(selected.date);` and it works fine. I am just curious, is `valueOf()` needed?

Comment: Once we set StartDate and EndDate, how to reset to default?

Answer (score 12):

I don't have enough reputation tocomment on Razzildinho's excellent answer, but did want to offer one small addition that will help users, which is to highlight the selected day on the second datepicker. You can do this by adding this line:

```
$('#enddate').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
```

So in context it will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#startdate").datepicker({
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#enddate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    $('#enddate').datepicker('setDate', minDate); // <--THIS IS THE LINE ADDED
});

$("#enddate").datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#startdate').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
    });

});
```

Comment: Good one. I have used this on my app. Works perfectly.