# Why My Min and Max date setting not working in my date picker?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I previously asked question to set one date picker dates with respect to month/year change of another date picker. I didn't get exact answer, but somehow I managed to get min and max dates to set to a date picker by referring various stack overflow answers. But that min and max date settings are not working properly.

Month and year picking date picker:

```
 <label> Month</label>
 <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtMonth" onchange="MonthDatePick();">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

My selected month date picking datepicker:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <label> From</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtFrom">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function MonthDatePick() {
  var month = $('#txtMonth').datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;//('getMonth');            
var year = $('#txtMonth').datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();//('getFullYear');   
var minDate = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
 var maxDate = new Date(year,month, 0);
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    //defaultDate:minDate,
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
});
}
```

I debugged and found out that when I select month, min and max dates were defined. 
For Ex: If I choose, `Feb 2018` means,

```
min date comes as :01/02/2018

max date comes as : 28/02/2018,
```

but the change does not replicate in my date selecting date picker

Debugging image picture

[image]

Debugging image picture showing min date

[image]

Here is  [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjwsvu5/)

How to fix this?

Comment: I dont see the minDate and maxDate properties in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#maxviewmode). Are you sure they are valid?

Comment: **Be careful:** There are two *nearly* identical jQuery plugins, both with the name *Datepicker*. One is the Bootstrap Datepicker, the other is the jQueryUI Datepicker. They have minor differences that could be responsible for your issues here. For example, jQueryUI datepicker uses [`minDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate), but the Bootstrap Datepicker uses [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate). If you are in fact using the Bootstrap datepicker (as you've tagged), then your properties are incorrect.

Comment: @TylerRoper Kindly check my question that I edited and added image of my debugging picture, that shows min/max date, in this I choosed march 2019, so It shows march date.

Comment: @Riya are you using bootstrap-datepicker or jqueryUI datepicker?

Comment: The value of your `minDate` variable being correct doesn't tell us much; as Below the Radar asks, we will need to know which datepicker you're truly using, because they use different property names. Better yet, your question should include a [**minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it's [off-topic (#1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I tried with the start date/end date property too ,still its not working.   `<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <script src="~/Content/adminlte/components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>` this is the datepicker that I am using so I tagged with bootstrap datepicker

Comment: @Riya Perhaps rather than recreating the whole datepicker, you should simply set the property you're trying to change: `$('#txtFrom').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);`? (suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456270/bootstrap-datepicker-change-mindate-startdate-from-another-datepicker))

Comment: @TylerRoper Kindly check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zdjwsvu5/

Comment: `setstartdate` too not working for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

HTML Code :

```
<label> Month</label>
<div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtMonth" onchange="MonthDatePick();">
<div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
<label> From</label>
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtFrom">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#txtMonth").datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   startView: "months", 
   minViewMode: "months",
   format: 'M-yyyy',
   //defaultDate:minDate,
   changeMonth: false,
   changeYear: false,
});

function MonthDatePick() {
   var month = $('#txtMonth').datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;//('getMonth');            
   var year = 
   $('#txtMonth').datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();//('getFullYear');   
   var minDate = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
   minDate = minDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
   var maxDate = new Date(year,month, 0);
   maxDate = maxDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
   $("#txtFrom").datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: minDate,
      endDate: maxDate,
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      //defaultDate:minDate,
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false,
   });
  $('#txtFrom').datepicker('setDate',minDate);
}
</script>
```

Output of the code :

[image]

Comment: wow..your one work like awesome.. this fixed my problem that I was struck more than 2 weeks.. thank u so much...

Comment: can u kindly explain `minDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');` this line plz, what does en-GB stands for?

Comment: @Riya Here i am using `toLocaleDateString('en-GB')` if you will change the format of date then you also need to change this. Because you are using `dd/mm/yyyy` so this format is fit for this situation.

Comment: @Riya `minDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')` this will convert your date to `dd/mm/yyyy`
If you will use `minDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US')` then it will give `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Is there any way to display min date that is `01/01/2021` to the `from` textbox after selecting month and yea,defautly? ,coz default date not working for me...

Comment: Yes
Just add `$('#txtFrom').val(minDate);` after initialising datepicker in `MonthDatePic()`

Comment: I found it my self, adding this line  `$('#txtFrom').datepicker('setDate',minDate);`  at the end of my monthdatepick()-before the closing braces,fixed my requirement.. kindly add this line in ur given answer, so that,it exactly satisfies my need and will help others in future too.. thank you

Comment: sir even ur solution working too..`$('#txtFrom').val(minDate);`. But I saw this after posted my comment only.. so adding ur one also fine,no issues...

Comment: This answer worked for me,so I ticked it as right answer. I dont know who gave down vote. It will be better, if u explain, y u gave down votes with reason..so that we can understand too right??

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct options:

```
  function MonthDatePick() {
      var month = $('#txtMonth').datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;//('getMonth');            
      var year = $('#txtMonth').datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();//('getFullYear');   
      var minDate = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
      var maxDate = new Date(year,month, 0);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: minDate,
        endDate: maxDate,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        //defaultDate:minDate,
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
      });
    }
```

Change `minDate` with `startDate` and `maxDate` with `endDate`

See [bootstrap-datepicker documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#)

Comment: I tried start date end date now, that too not working, my `'txtfrom'` datepicker just shows all month dates with current date as default

Answer (score 1):

You're currently attempting to recreate an existing datepicker. Instead, modify the current instance using the `setStartDate` and `setEndDate` methods.

```
$("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker("setStartDate", minDate);
$("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker("setEndDate", maxDate);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtClaimMonth').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "MM yyyy",
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
  });
  $('#txtClaimFrom').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  })
});

function MonthDatePick() {
  var month = $('#txtClaimMonth').datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1; //('getMonth');            
  var year = $('#txtClaimMonth').datepicker('getDate').getFullYear(); //('getFullYear');   
  var minDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  var maxDate = new Date(year, month, 0);
  $("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker("setStartDate", minDate);
  $("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker("setEndDate", maxDate);
}
```

```css
.col-lg-3 { margin-bottom: 180px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <label>Claim Month</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtClaimMonth" onchange="MonthDatePick();">
    <div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <label>Claim From</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtClaimFrom">
    <div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could `remove` the current datepicker and re-initialize it from scratch. Note that Bootstrap Datepicker uses `startDate` and `endDate` as options, not `minDate` and `maxDate`.

```
$("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker("remove");
$("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: minDate,
  endDate: maxDate,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtClaimMonth').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "MM yyyy",
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
  });
  $('#txtClaimFrom').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  })
});

function MonthDatePick() {
  var month = $('#txtClaimMonth').datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1; //('getMonth');            
  var year = $('#txtClaimMonth').datepicker('getDate').getFullYear(); //('getFullYear');   
  var minDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  var maxDate = new Date(year, month, 0);
  $("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker("remove");
  $("#txtClaimFrom").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: minDate,
    endDate: maxDate,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
  });
}
```

```css
.col-lg-3 {
  margin-bottom: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <label>Claim Month</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtClaimMonth" onchange="MonthDatePick();">
    <div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <label>Claim From</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtClaimFrom">
    <div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried ur one sir, but not working for me sir.. Mr. Amit Kumar answer worked for me sir.. THank you so much for ur replies and help sir..